# How can I re-factorise this circular nesting dictionary function?

Tags: python, nested, circular-dependency

### The challenge:

> I recently received a data extract with a list of folder names and associated subfolders. The challenge was to produce a reusable function that could provide a summary of the unique folder names and all the nested subfolders.
>
> The data source was an excel spreadsheet containing 2 columns:
>
> Parent: Folder name
>
> Child: Subfolder name
>
> Note: I have recreated spreadsheet data using pandas so the code can be easily tested.

**Create table:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Parent': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'C'],
        'Child': ['B', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'Z', 'Z', 'B', 'A']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df):

Parent  Child
0   A   B
1   B   C
2   C   E
3   D   E
4   E   Z
5   F   Z
6   C   B
7   C   A
```

### My solution:

```
def relationship_dictionary(dataframe, key_column_name, values_column_name):
    """
    The key_column_name is the primary data source that should be considered the 
    start of the nested relationship.
    
    The values_column_name is the subfolder
    
    Creates a dictionary of unique relationships to each key.
    """
    
    parent = key_column_name
    child = values_column_name
​
    d = {}
    for i, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        key = row[parent]
        value = row[child]
        if key in d.keys():
            d[key].append(value)
        else:
            d[key] = [value]
        
    for k, values in d.items():
        for v in values:
            if v in d.keys():
                for each in d[v]:
                    if (each not in d[k]) and (each != k):
                        d[k].extend([each])
    return d
```

### Result:

```
relationship_dictionary(df, "Parent", "Child")
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'E', 'Z'],
 'B': ['C', 'E', 'A', 'Z'],
 'C': ['E', 'B', 'A', 'Z'],
 'D': ['E', 'Z'],
 'E': ['Z'],
 'F': ['Z']}
```

### Feedback

> I'm happy to say it works after mitigating the circular nesting issue but I can't help thinking there is a far simpler way of doing this so I thought I'd put it out there for critique so feedback would be welcome... :)

Comment: Don't use `&`, which is a bitwise boolean operator.  Use `and` instead, which is a logical operator.  For instance, `1 & 2` is `0`.  Also, `and` will short-circuit, which `&` will not, so it can be more efficient.

Comment: @TomKarzes That is really useful to know so big thanks. Now off to gain a greater understanding the use of bitwise operators...

Comment: If is works, you could try to post the question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You could get more extensive answers there...

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta, big learning day for me!!!